# how to make Textbox text as Hyperlink in WPF

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I want to make textbox text as Hyperlink. Suppose if the type www.google.com as tetxbox text,when i click on the text ,it show open the link in a browser..

I could not get any idea to implement this...can u suggest me any idea...i tried the two ways.

way1:

```
  <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Name="txtWebPage" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextDecorations="UnderLine" TextChanged="txtWebPage_TextChanged" Foreground="Blue">
                                </TextBox>
```

way2:

```
 <TextBlock Name="tbWebpage" Grid.Row="4" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" >
                                    <Hyperlink></Hyperlink>
                                </TextBlock>
```

way3:

```
   <RichTextBox Grid.Row="4" Name="rtxtWeb" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" IsDocumentEnabled="True" Foreground="Blue" LostFocus="rtxtWeb_LostFocus">
                                    <FlowDocument>
                                        <Paragraph>
                                            <Hyperlink NavigateUri=""/>
                                        </Paragraph>
                                    </FlowDocument>
                                </RichTextBox>
```

I couldnt get how can i bind the RichTextBox text to Hyperlink uri!!! There is no click event for richtextbox...any suggestion please...

Comment: You want to make text as hyperlink if it is URI of the website, yes?

Comment: Yes...thats what i want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this... if the text becomes a clickable hyperlink the instant it's a valid URI, how would you continue to edit it?

The Hyperlink control doesn't do anything special for you and it can't be hosted in a TextBox. Instead, use a regular TextBox, check the text for a valid URI every time it's updated, and apply a style to make the text look like a clickable link.

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasValidURI}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF2A6DCD"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Every time the text is changed, `TextBox_TextChanged` is called. This checks whether the text is a valid URI using [`Uri.TryCreate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx). If so, a property `HasValidURI` is set to `true`. A `DataTrigger` in the `TextBox's` style picks this up and makes the text underlined and blue.

Making the hyperlink immediately clickable would cause you not to be able to position the cursor, so I watch for a double-click instead. When one is received, convert the text to a URI again and kick off a `Process` with that URI.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _hasValidURI;

    public bool HasValidURI
    {
        get { return _hasValidURI; }
        set { _hasValidURI = value; OnPropertyChanged( "HasValidURI" ); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged( string name )
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged( object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        Uri uri;
        HasValidURI = Uri.TryCreate( (sender as TextBox).Text, UriKind.Absolute, out uri );
    }

    private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        Uri uri;
        if( Uri.TryCreate( (sender as TextBox).Text, UriKind.Absolute, out uri ) )
        {
            Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo( uri.AbsoluteUri ) );
        }
    }
}
```